# load records in datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have this script where my table is generated in the submit page and i am trying to apply datatables to it, but its not working in that case.

Here is my code

```
$("#formSubmit").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    var form = $(this);
    var actionUrl = form.attr('action');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: actionUrl,
        data: form.serialize(),
        encode: true,
        success: function(data) {
            $('.container').html(data);
        },
        dataType: "html"
    });
});
```

my datatables are loaded in the end of the page and i am just lost what is wrong in here and what should i do apply datatables to the data response which is coming from the submitted page and being loaded in the container div

code already added above

Comment: **always check your selectors** - ie just before you code (outside the handler) add `console.log($("##formSubmit").length)` - if you get nothing, your code isn't being run - if you get 0 (zero) your selector is wrong.  `##id` certainly *looks* wrong.

Comment: that is a typo mistake when i was writing code in here, i edit my question now, please check

Comment: Assuming you do mean https://datatables.net, you've not initiated your datatable after setting the html.   Datatables.net are not "dynamic" - they only apply to the HTML as it is at the time you run `$(..).DataTable();`

Comment: i am no sure where i do it

Comment: I would hazard a guess at: `success: function(data) { $('.container').html(data); $('.container').find("table").DataTable(); }` but depends on your HTML etc - you might like to give your table a class in case you have other `<table>` elements - or if you have multiple tables that each need to be a datatable, you might need to `.each` them.

Comment: i did like the above you mentioned and also provided class to find it but i am getting an error `datatables.min.js:108 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'mData')
    at HTMLTableCellElement.<anonymous> (datatables.min.js:108:352)`

Comment: You need to have valid HTML.  Without the HTML can't help with your datatables issue - but the question is resolved.  I can add an answer "initialise datatables after setting html" to close this question even though it just creates a *new* issue.